# Place cursor back automatically into erroneous form field when js validation fails

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, field

Let's say there is a form field named txtphone and then with javascript I check it is at least 10 digits in length. User enters only 5 digits so validation fails. I want the cursor to go back to where the txtphone is input automatically so the user can not get any further without entering a 10 digit phone number. This is an example. I can not get it to go back to input field on fields like name, email, etc. On this example, on failure, this is how I am trying to accomplish this:

```
txtphone.focus()
txtphone.select()
return False
```

It shows the alert error message but the focus is placed on the next form field.

Please, respond only if you had this problem in the past and you solved it, and please, give me a few lines of actual working code. I have been fighting this for weeks and ready to give up. Answers like "have you tried..." do me no good. Thank you.

Comment: more code please... using focus is the right way, but your implementation may be wrong

Answer (score 3):

I created a JSFiddle showing how the focus method should work for what you're looking for. Let me know if it helps.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qpuu8q0r/)

HTML

```
<input id="txtphone" type="text">

<button id="btn">
Click me!
</button>
```

JavaScript

```
var txtphone = document.getElementById("txtphone");

var button = document.getElementById("btn");

button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (txtphone.value.length < 10) {
    txtphone.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    txtphone.focus();
  } else {
    txtphone.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
});
```